# count word frequency with out dictionary in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I have file input which is alphabetically sorted

```
Asburn 9
Ashley 10
Ashley 11
Bojourn 12
```

I want the output like

```
Asburn 9 
Ashley 21 
Bojourn 12
```

Code I have used :

```
counts = defaultdict(int)
for line in sys.stdin:
 word, count  = line.split()
 counts[word] += int(count)
  for wrd, count in counts.items():
     print("{}\t{}".format(wrd,count))
```

but I cannot used dictionary. How should I implement it

Comment: What is the issue here? Why can't you use a dictionary?

Comment: Why not use a dictionary? Is this homework? What have your tried so far.

Comment: If you can't use the built in dictionary, implement your own dictionary and use that.

Comment: It a required not to use dictionary as part of the problem

Comment: What is the *exact phrasing*?  This is such a dumb assignment that I'm willing to help you find the evil genie loophole but I need to see the wording.

Comment: @Samwise If you think they *need* a dict then I think you overlooked that the input is already sorted.

Comment: I did, but you're still just building a dictionary.

Comment: @Samwise but it can be done without a dictionary in a reasonable fashion. Voting to re-open

Comment: @RiccardoBucco The question begins with *"I have file input which is alphabetically sorted"*.

Comment: and since Ashley was repeated the counted got added

Comment: Can you use itertools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
prev_word = None
prev_count = 0
for line in sys.stdin:
    word, count  = line.split()
    count = int(count)
    if word != prev_word:
        if prev_word is not None:
            print(prev_word, str(prev_count))
        prev_count = count
        prev_word = word
    else:
        prev_count += count
if prev_word != None:
    print(prev_word, prev_count)
```

Quick test: the following code returns the expected output

```
prev_word = None
prev_count = 0
for line in ['ashutosh 9', 'ashutosh 10', 'check 11', 'check 11', 'zebra 11']:
    word, count  = line.split()
    count = int(count)
    if word != prev_word:
        if prev_word is not None:
            print(prev_word, prev_count)
        prev_count = count
        prev_word = word
    else:
        prev_count += count
if prev_word != None:
    print(prev_word, prev_count)
```

Comment: I am getting ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0) with the above logic. Using python 3

Comment: Then your input is wrong @bhalkian The line failing is probably `word, count  = line.split()`. Please be more specific about the input settings...

Comment: Its not printing the last element, I think its failing at boundary condition

Answer (score 2):

With some help from Python's standard library:

```
from sys import stdin
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

for word, group in groupby(map(str.split, stdin), itemgetter(0)):
    print(word, sum(int(count) for _, count in group))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1LDsIwDET3OYWXiRQhChtgVy6CWvoLamLLcYR6@pK2aoVXnhm/MU0yYLjeiOe5Y/QQpwjOE7JAlMYFtbpOWhbE8ch6xkT1tKVILVeCvIf52vetZEapLttf5MZuCLiws9pXpKPwKdLoxG7vjP2j9dmYh4I8xC6I3npi8npRb0xBDCwPXhZWdbQbM89lrBMHuKsyDmM7QXE@tkI98YNLWlx@)

Comment: True magic! Great idea to pass the `itemgetter` as `key` of `groupby`!

Comment: @cards Meh, this is all boring standard stuff. I wasn't even sure I'd post it, in the end I mainly did for a comparison with the answers that reimplemented `groupby` themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Used a regex to list the key-value like terms, group them by the key, decouple the keys-values of each group with `zip`.

```
import re
import itertools as it

text = """Asburn 9
Ashley 10
Ashley 11
Bojourn 12"""

pairs = re.findall(r'^(.+?)\s(\d+)\n*', text, re.M)

groups = [zip(*grp) for _, grp in it.groupby(pairs, lambda p: p[0])]

for keys, values in groups:
    print(keys[0], sum(map(int, values)))
```